# How to set props to component in Vue.js in script section (without rendering)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to import component A with props and pass it to another component B. It must be rendered in component B.

```
import MyComponent from '/MyComponent.vue'

computed: {
    compnt: function () {
        var comp = MyComponent      
        // How can I set props to MyComponent? 
        return comp 
    }
}
```

What should I do to set props to component A ?

Comment: What problem do you have? Just pass it and render as dynamic component. This could be XY problem, as this is commonly done through slots in Vue

Comment: I pass component_A to componentB as a prop of component_B. In component_B I use slot to render component_A in another component_C. But I need to set props to  component_A in parent component.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it gives better idea of your case  than a description of the code. "parent component" - who's a parent? As I said, it's commonly done with slots, where you can provide props altogether with a component

Comment: "with slots, where you can provide props altogether with a component" Yes, I know about this option. This means I need to pass my props not in component_A directly, but pass them in component_B together with component_A. It looks terrible from an object-oriented point of view, but vue doesn't seem to know any other way.

Comment: FWIW, Vue never followed OOP paradigm. And it clearly leans towards FP in Vue 3. I don't see design problems with this, slots aren't universal but they provide a solid pattern for parent-child interaction. "but pass them in component_B together with component_A" - not sure what you meant. With a slot, you pass the whole thing that needs to be rendered, a component plus its props. Consider updating the question with your case if you're interested in getting an answer that keeps it into account

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to share data between components it's best to use [`vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). You can define a variable in the `state` like this

```js
# store/store.js
//...
state: {
  count: 0
}
// ...
```

And use it in any component you want like this.

```html
<template>
  <span>{{ count }}</span>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  // ...
  computed: mapState(['count'])
  // ...
}
</script>
```

You can follow [this tutorial](https://flaviocopes.com/vuex/) for more information

Comment: Thank you. That is, as I understand it, in Vue there is no way to pass parameters to the component constructor if this component is not presented in the template, as, for example, it is done in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the data between components you can use below solution

Create the EventBus.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

In your component file use below code

```
import { EventBus } from "../EventBus.js";
export default { 
  mounted() {
      var myData = "Hi"; 
      EventBus.$emit("sendIndex", myData );
    };
  },
};
```

Access your data in the component as

```
import { EventBus } from "../EventBus.js";
export default { 
  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('sendIndex', data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this option I also know. I thought it is possible to pass the props of component (object) to the component (object) itself, in OOP-style, without resorting to the tricks of using store or bus.